# Indian passport slight water mark. Is this considered damaged?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, damaged-passports

My Indian passport has got some slight water mark in it now. Is this considered damaged passport or will it be fine. The pages which has my details are all intact. It is just the first page cover[image] and slightly on the edges.  Will I need to get a new one replaced. I have a visa appointment on Monday :(

Comment: I had my (Russian) passport damaged by water in 2016 (I got under a heavy rain when it was in my rucksack, which was not tightly closed). Some exit/entry stamps were smudged to partial illegibility or smeared other pages, photos and text on some visa stickers were also slightly smudged. I am still using that passport, and only once I was asked "what happened to it?" I know that anecdotal evidence is no proof, but it seems that as long as your passport still looks genuine enough and serves to identify you, it is still OK to travel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the link in Traveller's answer carefully.

They don't define what a "damaged passport" is, but they distinguish between "just damaged passport", where the passport number and name are readable and the photo is intact, and "damaged beyond recognition", where that is not the case. You passport is not "damaged beyond recognition". Whether it is considered damaged is not clear from that site.

Important quote for you: "In case your passport has not been damaged beyond recognition, i.e. passport number is legible, name is legible and photo is intact, then you can apply for re-issue of passport under the Tatkaal scheme. But, if passport has been damaged beyond recognition, then you cannot apply under the Tatkaal scheme. In that case, you need to visit Passport Officer at your nearest Passport Seva Kendra to get the passport on urgent basis." So getting a new passport is easier for you, the same site has a link for "re-issue of passport.

It looks to me that they mean something much more serious with "damaged". For example, if a page inside was torn out - that would count as damaged. Your passport still contains all the information that it is supposed to contain, so it should not cause you problems at a visa interview. You *might* be told to bring a new passport when the visa is issued,

Comment: Agree. It seems it is a bit vague and doesn't clearly say whether it is acceptable or not. I have decided to get a new passport under the Tatkaal scheme anyway. Thanks all for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports the definition of a damaged passport is:

- Passport number is readable, name is legible and photo is intact
- Damaged beyond recognition

Based on your question, your passport seems acceptable.