# My passport has coffee stains on a number of pages. The biometric data page is completely unaffected. I am travelling to Berlin tomorrow

Tags: damaged-passports

Coffee stains on pages of passport. Everything is still legible. The biometric page is unaffected. Can I travel with this passport? I am due to fly to Berlin tomorrow and will replace it on my return.

Comment: Typically some smudges, stains and dog ears are expected since passports are "working documents". However, we can't possibly tell you whether your specific  is potential trouble without seeing it. Since you are leaving tomorrow, you probably will have to chance it.

Comment: Passport issued by which country?  Flying to Berlin from which airport?

Comment: It's hard to be certain. Is it just discolouration blotches on a few pages? Often, especially if there is no requirement for visa or recording exit/entry in the passport, people will only look at the identity page (with your photo and basic details), and as long as that's OK and the damage to the rest of your passport isn't too drastic, you'll probably be OK. But some passports are known to be commonly forged or stolen, and in some cases they may look more closely. (As Hilmar says, your best option is probably to chance it, as even a refusal is unlikely to seriously impact on you.)

Comment: [This question is about water damage and includes a photo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135598/indian-passport-slight-water-mark-is-this-considered-damaged)

Comment: At this point, there's probably no harm in trying. Almost certainly you won't be able to replace it within 24 hours.